# How to i correctly attatch an instance of a registered component to a scene in Aframe?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I want to create a new Component in Aframe and attach it to my scene. But i don't quite get how it is supposed to be used.

For example i have this component line:
How do i create an instance of the component and attatch it to my scene?
Also how do i correctly set the parameters upon creation?

I have taken a look at the Aframe docs which sais to do as follows:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('hello-world', {
  init: function () {
    console.log('Hello, World!');
  }
});

document.querySelector('a-scene').setAttribute('hello-world', '');
```

but that Example isn't enough for me to know how to use it.

I want to create multiple instances of this component:
I hope you can help me.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('line', {
    schema: {
      color: {type: 'string', default: '#8b4513'},
      points: {type: 'array', default: []},
    },

    init: function () {
      console.log(this.data.color);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attaching a component called `hello-world` can be achieved in multiple ways:

```
// no properties / default 
setAttribute('hello-world', '')
// assuming there are properties in the schema
setAttribute('hello-world', 'property', 'value')
setAttribute('hello-world', {
  'propertyOne': 'valueOne',
  'propertyTwo': 'valueTwo'
})
// another instance - if multiple enabled
setAttribute('hello-world__one', 'property', 'value')
```

---

You can have multiple instances of your component attached, if you define its `multiple` property:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', 
   multiple: true
   // .....
})
```

You can attach multiple components like this:

```
<a-entity foo="" foo__one="" foo__two=""></a-entity>
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3yp87h5m/1/). It's also quite well documented [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/core/component.html#multiple).

---

Taking lines as an example, you can simply have a 'manager' entity, with the lines attached.

```
<script>
   AFRAME.registerComponent('line-manager', {
      init: function() {
         this.el.setAttribute("line__one", {
           "start": '0 0 0",
           "end": '1 2 3'
         })
         this.el.setAttribute("line__two", {
           "start": '0 0 0",
           "end": '3 2 1'
         })
      }
   })
</script>
<a-scene>
   <a-entity line-manager></e-entity>
```

Maybe [this](https://jsfiddle.net/u8ngmpsh/) fiddle could help.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! If i want to attatch multiple for example lines to my scene should i just use setAttribute for the scene or should i create a new entity and then attatch the component to the entity and add the entity as a child to the scene ? thanks in advance :) or am i even using this correctly? should it be used for creating objects in a scene ?

Comment: @RezarakSL i've updated the anwser, let me know if it helps

Comment: I now tried to use RegisterGeometry instead since i think its better for my problem, but again the website doesn't show how to use it within javasctipt: https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/geometry.html can it be used like a primitive ? for example with document.createelement('name) where name is the name od the registered Geometry?

Comment: If you do have a geometry you can assign to `this.geometry` then check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phu3r6fo/3/). You can also make a primitive out of custom components - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phu3r6fo/4/).

Comment: These are two great examples on how to create them thanks they helped alot! But the instances are used within html and my last remaining problem is that i don't know how to make an instance programatically within javascript. Could you also show me an Example of that ? :)

Comment: Yes exactly like that, thanks for your answer, i would upvote it but i don't have enough reputation xD